# How to quick view the value of NSCFString in debugger window?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Which is the quickest way to view the value of a NSCFString variable in debugger window?

As for NSString, the string value is automatically displayed in the window or you move your mouse over it. But for a  NSCFString, I tried same but cannot find the internal string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the program stops in your breakpoint, did you try typing the following into xcode's output console

```
po myNSCFString
```

being `myNSCFString` your `NSCFString` variable.